# Check C# COM DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, interop

I wrote a COM library in C # ,  Everythings is ok (I think):

1. compilation successfull
2. OLE objects are in the registry with Prog.ID and guid

How Can I include this dll in c# console app but only with OLE Interop ? 
I see properties 'Embed Interop Types' - true/false but it's not work for me.

Comment: you can right click on the project and add a reference to that dll have you tried that..?

Comment: I include this dll but I would like to check OLE object . How Can I hide .NET Assembly ?

Comment: "Other public members in the class that are not declared in these interfaces will not be visible to COM, but they will be visible to other .NET Framework objects."

Comment: The IDE will defeat any attempt at adding a reference to the type library.  It can see that the component was actually written in .NET.  It not like you can't fool it (use late binding with the *dynamic* keyword), but the CLR is not fooled either and you won't actually exercise the COM interface like the intended client app will do.  So it is a pretty pointless exercise, test it by actually using the intended client app dev tools.  Now you can be sure it works.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks